# Java - Delete folder independent if empty or full

Tags: java, directory

I have the need to delete a folder/directory or content regardless if you have not, only for JAVA

```
folder.delete()
```

that does not work.

I been looking, but they are outdated methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
   FileUtils.deleteDirectory(File directory);
```

For more info go to [link1](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteDirectory%28java.io.File%29) and [link2](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi)

Comment: cannot find symbol FileUtils

Comment: @Cazs try to download it in [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/f/Downloadfileutilsjar.htm)

Comment: @Cazs I changed the link

Comment: although I like your method, I can not use external libraries ... activity rules

Answer (score 0):

`folder.delete()` will only delete the folder *if it is empty*.

If you want to delete an entire folder tree you will need to walk it, delete all the files within it and then delete the folder itself.

You can use `Files.walkFileTree` to accomplish this:

```
public static void deleteEntireFolder(File folder) throws IOException {
    if (!folder.isDirectory()) {
        folder.delete();
        return;
    }

    Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(
            folder.getAbsolutePath()),//The folder path
            EnumSet.of(FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS),//Do you want to go through shortcuts?
            100,//How many folders deep you want to walk.
            new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {

                    file.toFile().delete();

                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
            });
}
```

You will probably need to refine this method, but as it stands it *should* get the job done.